# How do I handle tableview cell values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, tableview

I have a tableview which contains custom cells where each cell has some PDF documents.

I need to handle those PDFs using array and dictionary but I don't know how to do that. Are there any examples on how to do this or should I maintain the values in plist?

Comment: This seems to be a broad question and hard to understand the specifics.

Comment: the use of subjects and punctation may would lead to a more understandable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Basheer said,  you should create delegate for your custom cell, you have created. Then assign indexPath.row method to the custom cell. Implement touchesBegan to get the tag value of custom cell and then finally use that tag value as index of an array of your table.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from your question, you want to know which custom cell is clicked in the table view?

Assuming, you are loading the table using an array.

Create a delegate in Custom Cell and delegate api should give you the tag value of the custom cell.

While creating the custom cell, assign the indexPath.row to the custom cell tag property.

Then implement the touchesBegan api in the custom cell view and use the delegate to get the tag value.

Now use the tag value as index of the array from which you loaded the table.